# First time using SFML-2.5.1 in NetBeans IDE 8.2 I ran into the problem

Tags: c++, c++14, mingw, sfml, mingw32

After the setup I've done in the properties of the project: at [C++Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eukpi.png) and [Linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVMKm.png) in both Release and Debug configurations I tried to build the project, which went successful.

Then I decided to run it and had some difficulties: using [External Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8guOE.png), that did absolutely nothing, [Standard output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zRbW.png), that showed some text related to dll files I've clue about, [Internal Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9ZFq.png), that showed the very same text.

After that didn't work I went for cmd execution and what I saw was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX2KQ.png).

Could you explain what that means and what I'm supposed to do. I'm new to all that kind of stuff, so I apologise if I did something stupid.

Cheers

EDIT: If not seen, I'm using Windows 10 and the version of SFML is GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (DW2) - 32-bit

Comment: Make sure the proper `.dll` files are in the same directory as your `.exe`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should've specified I'd been using static and seemingly not in of bin dll files. Yet even when I tried it with them it din't work.

Comment: If your using MinGW and GCC on windows, there are dll files that are needed for that aswell. Not just the SFML ones.

Comment: Cheers, you helped me a whole lot!